# ConTeXt: line numbering disappears in custom column layout

Tags: context, line-numbering

Line numbering disappears when called inside custom columns defined with `defineparagraph`.

This works fine

```
\defineparagraphs[Colonne][n=2]
\starttext
\startlinenumbering 
\input knuth
\stoplinenumbering

\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Whereas this does not work as expected

```
\defineparagraphs[Colonne][n=2]
\starttext
\startColonne
\startlinenumbering 
\input knuth
\stoplinenumbering
\Colonne

\input knuth
\stopColonne
\stoptext
```

Playing with `\setuplinenumbering` (`location=text` and so on) didn't help. Maybe this has to do with setting margins in `defineparagraphs`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I think the line numbering mechanism only operates on the shipout box.

Comment: @HenriMenke I understand you read the code and that there is not much to be done. Do you think this would make sense to post my question on ConTeXt mailing list?

Comment: It always makes sense to post a question to the ConTeXt list.